# Creating Vhosts with Webmin

Tags: linux, apache, webmin

I have been messing around with webmin and creating vhosts, now normally I would just shh into the box and create them manually but the other developers in the office are not too confident doing that.

Creating the Vhost is fine but when its saves to 'sites-available' it adds .conf at the end of the file name, this is not causing any problems other than slightly annoying me. Is there anyway to set webmin to not add this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you award this if it helped ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In:**     `Webmin > Apache Webserver > Module Config`

**Option:** `"Filename pattern for virtual servers"` set to `"Default ($DOM.conf)"`

**just change it to your liking :)**